# Ignore any specific casing of response object in .NET core 2.2 WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, output-formatting, webapi

In .NET core Webapi, by default, return json is in camel case and can be formatted to return title case. That is fine.Is it possible to ignore the case completely.Means, the return json name and property value should be as it is returned from the service.No casing to be applied. Whether it possible? for example, if return json object name is "jsonname" it should return the same instead of "jsonName"

Answer (score 0):

You could custom `DefaultContractResolver`:

```
public class LowercaseContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        return propertyName;
    }
}
```

Register in Startup.cs for global serialize:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new LowercaseContractResolver()
    };
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

You could test like below:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<string> Get()
{
    var user = new User()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "aa",
        MyAddress = "sad"
    };

    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
    return data;
}
```

Or you could set for output json like below:

```
return new JsonResult(user, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new LowercaseContractResolver() });
```

Comment: This will make to Title case instead of default camel case. But the question is to ignore the casing completely.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: this will convert property to lowercase always? bcs the need is to get it as it is. If PropertyName is camel case it should return as camel if pascal case it should return as pascal case.Not everything to lowercase. If remove the .ToLower() will it work without any case conversion?

Comment: Yes,that's it.It is my fault that misunderstood your requirement.Just remove .ToLower().